# Is this possible to clear python shell without os.system("clear")?

Tags: python, os.system

*Python is lovely to me because of short line code. 

Is there any other way to clear Python shell without using:*

> **import os
>  
>   os.system('clear')**

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest you to use ipython-notebook. 
It is very friendly and also supports the shell commands directly.